# Function not console logging when called by other function

Tags: javascript

I have `2 functions` on a single `.js` file.

```
function notUsed(id) {
        //default to false because if true then id not being used and good for new user
        var notInUse = false;

        console.log(notInUse);
        return !notInUse;   
    }

function generateID() {

        //number of zeros represents the number of digits in id code
        const SIZEOFID = 10000000;
        const ID_DIGITS = 7;
        //letter to start id for non los rios people
        const STRTOFID = "C";
        //variable to hold finished id code & variable to hold 7 digit of id code
        var id, idNum;

        //loop to make sure id contains 7 digits and 1 letter and not used already
        do {
            idNum = Math.round(Math.random() * SIZEOFID);
            idNum.toString();
            id = (STRTOFID + idNum);
        }while(id.length != (ID_DIGITS+1) && notUsed(id));
        console.log(id);
    }
```

When I call `generateID()` from my web page, the `ID` gets logged but `false` does not get logged(Obviously notUsed function is incomplete). However, if I call each `function` separately from my web page, both the `ID` and `false` get logged. How can I fix or work around this issue? Any comments help.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: @Dij the ID getting logged is just a random ID with a single character and 7 digits

Comment: @MarcoSalerno when calling generateID() from inside a script tag on a web page?

Comment: Apparantly notUsed(id) is not executed. id.length != (ID_DIGITS+1) returns false so second operand is not evaluated

Comment: I tried it inside stack overflow's snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical and is short-circuiting because the first comparison is false.  The second never gets evaluated, which is why it's not logging.  It's not being called.

Comment: How can I fix that if it is possible?

Comment: @NickPavini You probably want to use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Well if the purpose is to verify that the ID as generated is not used by another user, then just call `notUsed` only.  Your code as written will guarantee the length of `idNum` to be 8 characters, I don't think you need that check.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson but I need both circumstances to be true.

Comment: @NickPavini `!(A && B) == !A || !B`

Comment: You can try by changing the order - notUsed(id)) &&  (ID_DIGITS+1)

Answer (score 1):

It`s happened because first condition in while id.length != (ID_DIGITS+1) return false, if first condition return false next conditions will not be called

**Example**:

```
function imreturnTrue() {
  console.log('imreturnTrue');
  return true
};

function impreturnFalse() {
   console.log('impreturnFalse');
   return false
};

function imreturnTrue1() {
    console.log('imreturnTrue1');
    return true
};
let example = imreturnTrue() && impreturnFalse() && imreturnTrue1();
// imreturnTrue impreturnFalse

let example1 = imreturnTrue() && imreturnTrue1() && impreturnFalse() ; 
// imreturnTrue imreturnTrue1 impreturnFalse

let example2 = impreturnFalse() && imreturnTrue() && imreturnTrue1() ; 
// impreturnFalse
```